# java how to stop when maximum number reached

Tags: java

i am doing a contact book information and only want to add maximum of 20 contacts but it only adds maximum of 10 contacts any help?

```
public class Book {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Contact> lsCont = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        Contact[] contacts = new Contact[20];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String phone;
        String email;

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("insert first name : ");
            firstName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("insert last Name : ");
            lastName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("insert phone : ");
            phone = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("insert email : ");
            email = scanner.nextLine();

            Contact cont = new Contact(firstName, lastName, phone, email);

            lsCont.add(cont);

            Collections.sort(lsCont);
            i++;
            for (Contact contact : lsCont) {
                System.out.println(contact.toString());

            }
            if (i == contacts.length) {
                System.out.println("maxiumum number of adding contact has reached");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing `i++` when declaring the loop, then do `i++;` again inside of the loop, remove the one inside of the loop.  This makes you iterate by values of 2 instead of 1, making your loop iterate 10 times instead of 20.

Comment: Why do you have `i++` in the middle of your loop?  You're mangling your loop counter and cutting your iterations in half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing the value of the variable `i` twice in your ***for*** loop, causing it to **increase by 2** every time. This causes the for loop to only run **half times**. To fix this you can simply remove the second `i++`.

Also, to make it more clear, I would suggest making an *int* variable `maxContacts`, then replacing the "20" inside the brackets with the name of the variable, and writing `maxContacts` instead of `contacts.length` to make the code more clear and readable!

Answer (score 3):

You are incrementing `i` twice. Remove `i++` in the body of the for loop.